# Assign multiple values to a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array that is declared as follow :

```
testCellArray = cell(m, n);
```

In a script, I specify the value of each cell as follow :

```
for loop (ii)
    testCellArray{ii, 1} = str2num(value1{ii});
    testCellArray{ii, 2} = str2num(value2{ii});
    testCellArray{ii, 3} = str2num(value3{ii});
    testCellArray{ii, 4} = str2num(value4{ii});
    ...
    testCellArray{ii, n} = str2num(valuen{ii});
end
```

I'm unable to put this in one line (I'm pretty sure it is possible).

I've tried something like this :

```
testCellArray{ii, :} = deal(str2num(value1{ii}, value2{ii}, value3{ii}, value4{ii}, ..., valuen{ii}))
```

But it isn't working. I'm also not sure if I should use `testCellArray{ii, :}` or `testCellArray(ii, :)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way would probably be the use of `str2double` instead of `str2num`, since it also takes a cell-array as input.

Than you could arrange the assignments as follows, without the outer `ii` loop:

```
testCellArray(:,1) = num2cell(str2double(value1));
testCellArray(:,2) = num2cell(str2double(value2));
...
testCellArray(:,n) = num2cell(str2double(valuen));
```

And, if your variables are really named `value1`, `value2` etc., I can't resist to recommend:
Get rid of enumerated variable names and put things into a list, presumably a cell-array in this case.

If you really need/want to keep the loop, the proper version of your deal assignment would be:

```
[testCellArray{ii, :}] = deal(str2num(value1{ii}), str2num(value2{ii}), ..., str2num(valuen{ii}));
```

However, not knowing how large `n` is, putting this in one gigantic line instead of several shorter ones surely isn't good coding style.

Comment: Right now `n = 16`. And no, the variables are not really named value1, value2, ...etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `value1`, `value2` etc are vertical cell arrays of strings:

```
testCellArray = num2cell([str2num(strvcat(value1{:})) str2num(strvcat(value2{:}))]);
```

Note that `strvcat` can handle strings witth different lengths.

Example:

```
>> value1 = {'1';'2';'3';'14'};
>> value2 = {'5';'6';'7';'182'};
>> testCellArray = num2cell([str2num(strvcat(value1{:})) str2num(strvcat(value2{:}))])

testCellArray = 

    [ 1]    [  5]
    [ 2]    [  6]
    [ 3]    [  7]
    [14]    [182]
```

---

It's much more convenient if all `value1`, `value2` etc are lumped into a single 2D cell array, such as:

```
value = {'1'  '5'   '-1';
         '2'  '6'   '-2';
         '3'  '7'   '-3';
         '14' '182' '-4'}; %// arbitrary number of columns
```

That way you don't have to modify the code to accomodate a varying number of columns. Just use

```
testCellArray = num2cell(reshape(str2num(strvcat(value{:})), size(value)));
```

or equivalently

```
testCellArray = mat2cell(str2double(value), ones(1,size(value,1)), ones(1,size(value,2)) );
```

to obtain the result

```
testCellArray = 

    [ 1]    [  5]    [-1]
    [ 2]    [  6]    [-2]
    [ 3]    [  7]    [-3]
    [14]    [182]    [-4]
```

Comment: The fact is that the lenght of value1, value2, ..., valuen are not the same. So I don't see how they could be put in a single 2D cell array.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with only one instruction:

```
testCellArray = cellfun(@str2num, [value1(:),value2(:),value3(:),...
  ,valuen(:)],'UniformOutput',false));
```

If all value* are vectical vectors, you can take `(:)` out.